# Order heatmap rows in ggplot2 facet plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, facet

I'm having a problem with faceted heatmap rendering in ggplot2. The idea is that I have several elements (these are genes in the real life) and several experiments (F1 and F2 in the example below). Using the F1 experiment, I'm able to create class of elements/genes based on their mean expression (high, ..., moderate, ..., low). In the heatmap produced through the example below, I would like to order each elements in each class (01, 02, 03, 04) based on its mean expression value in F1. Unfortunately, the elements appear in alphabetic order. I would be very happy to get some hints...
Best

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(123)

# let's create a fake dataset
nb.experiment <- 4
n.row <- 200
n.col <- 5
d <- matrix(round(runif(n.row * n.col),2), nc=n.col) 
colnames(d) <- sprintf("%02d", 1:5)

# These strings will be the row names of each heatmap
# in the subsequent facet plot
elements <- sample(replicate(n.row/2, rawToChar(as.raw(sample(65:90, 6, replace=T)))))


# let's create a data.frame d
d <- data.frame(d, 
                experiment = sort(rep(c("F1","F2"), n.row/2)),
                elements= elements)

# For elements related to experiment F1 
# we artificially produce a gradient of values that will
# create elements with increasing row means
d[d$experiment =="F1",1:5] <- round(sweep(d[d$experiment =="F1",1:5], 
                                          1, 
                                          seq(from=1, 10, length.out = 100), 
                                          "+"), 2)
# For elements related to experiment F2
# we artificially produce a gradient of values that will
# create elements with decreasing row means
d[d$experiment =="F2",1:5] <- round(sweep(d[d$experiment =="F2",1:5], 
                                          1, 
                                          seq(from=10, 1, length.out = 100), 
                                          "+"), 2)

#print(d[d$experiment =="F1",1:5])

# Now we split the dataset by experiments
d.split <- split(d, d$experiment)

# For all experiments, we order elements based on the mean expression signal in 
# F1.
row.means.F1 <- rowMeans(d.split$F1[,1:5])
pos <- order(row.means.F1)

for(s in names(d.split)){
  d.split[[s]] <- d.split[[s]][pos,]
}


# We create several classes of elements based on their 
# mean expression signal in F1.
cuts <- cut(1:nrow(d.split$F1), nb.experiment)
levels(cuts) <- sprintf("%02d", 1:nb.experiment)

for(s in names(d.split)){
  d.split[[s]] <- split(d.split[[s]], cuts)
}



# Data are melt (their is perhaps a better solution...)
# in order to use the ggplot function
dm <- melt(do.call('rbind',lapply(d.split, melt)), id.var=c( "experiment", "elements", "variable", "L1"))
dm <- dm[, -5]
colnames(dm) <- c("experiment","elements", "pos", "rowMeanClass", "exprs")


# Now we plot the data
p <- ggplot(dm, aes(x = pos, y = elements, fill = exprs))
p <- p + geom_raster()                                        
p <- p + facet_wrap(~rowMeanClass +experiment , scales = "free", ncol = 2)
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(size=4))
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(family = "mono", face = "bold"))

ggsave("RPlot_test.jpeg", p)
```

[image: example output]

Comment: if you use ordered factors the facets will order by that facet order.

Comment: I could create a factor corresponding to ordered elements (e.g a new column in d.split) and use it for subsequent display. But in this case It would change the element name (?). Or there is something I missed... Thanks for helping.

Comment: no, just use `factor(vector, levels=ORDEREDLISTOFvector, ordered=TRUE)`. So order it by the mean and it should be fine.

Comment: I manage do it, changing the element name. But I really don't see where to use something like factor(vector, levels=ORDEREDLISTOFvector, ordered=TRUE). Sorry...

Comment: @user451460 If you figured out a solution, please post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I have slightly edited the example and will post a solution asap.

Comment: @hrbrmstr the `ordered = TRUE` is unnecessary. **All** factors have an order for their levels that ggplot will respect. The only place I know of where it matters if your factor is truly an *ordered* factor with `ordered = TRUE` is in a model where you want the contrasts to be level 2 vs level 1, level 3 vs level 2, etc., instead of using level 1 as the reference level for all. (Well, also if you want to compare factor levels with `<` or the like.)

Comment: exactly @Gregor. that's what the OP wants, I think anyway. and i use ordered factors all the time to get the ordering i want from facet plots.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Specifying `ordered` is unnecessary. If you use `ordered = FALSE` (or don't specify `ordered` at all) you will still get the order you want from the facets. It **only** matters if you care about the type of contrasts you use in a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your advises I was able to find a solution (which implies to clearly specify the order of levels for the 'elements' factor). Thank you @hrbrmstr (and all others).

NB: I only added few lines compare to the original code that are denoted below with 'Added: begin' and 'Added: end' flags.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(123)

# let's create a fake dataset
nb.experiment <- 4
n.row <- 200
n.col <- 5
d <- matrix(round(runif(n.row * n.col),2), nc=n.col) 
colnames(d) <- sprintf("%02d", 1:5)

# These strings will be the row names of each heatmap
# in the subsequent facet plot
elements <- sample(replicate(n.row/2, rawToChar(as.raw(sample(65:90, 6, replace=T)))))


# let's create a data.frame d
d <- data.frame(d, 
                experiment = sort(rep(c("F1","F2"), n.row/2)),
                elements= elements)

# For elements related to experiment F1 
# we artificially produce a gradient of values that will
# create elements with increasing row means
d[d$experiment =="F1",1:5] <- round(sweep(d[d$experiment =="F1",1:5], 
                                          1, 
                                          seq(from=1, 10, length.out = 100), 
                                          "+"), 2)
# For elements related to experiment F2
# we artificially produce a gradient of values that will
# create elements with decreasing row means
d[d$experiment =="F2",1:5] <- round(sweep(d[d$experiment =="F2",1:5], 
                                          1, 
                                          seq(from=10, 1, length.out = 100), 
                                          "+"), 2)

#print(d[d$experiment =="F1",1:5])

# Now we split the dataset by experiments
d.split <- split(d, d$experiment)

# For all experiments, we order elements based on the mean expression signal in 
# F1.
row.means.F1 <- rowMeans(d.split$F1[,1:5])
pos <- order(row.means.F1)

for(s in names(d.split)){
  d.split[[s]] <- d.split[[s]][pos,]
}

## Added: begin ###
#Get the list of elements in proper order (based on row mean)
mean.order <- as.character(d.split$F1$elements)
## Added: end###

# We create several classes of elements based on their 
# mean expression signal in F1.
cuts <- cut(1:nrow(d.split$F1), nb.experiment)
levels(cuts) <- sprintf("%02d", 1:nb.experiment)

for(s in names(d.split)){
  d.split[[s]] <- split(d.split[[s]], cuts)
}



# Data are melt (their is perhaps a better solution...)
# in order to use the ggplot function
dm <- melt(do.call('rbind',lapply(d.split, melt)), id.var=c( "experiment", "elements", "variable", "L1"))
dm <- dm[, -5]
colnames(dm) <- c("experiment","elements", "pos", "rowMeanClass", "exprs")

## Added: begin###
#Ensure that dm$elements is an ordered factor with levels
# ordered as expected
dm$elements <- factor(dm$elements, levels = mean.order, ordered = TRUE)
## Added: end###

# Now we plot the data
p <- ggplot(dm, aes(x = pos, y = elements, fill = exprs))
p <- p + geom_raster()                                        
p <- p + facet_wrap(~rowMeanClass +experiment , scales = "free", ncol = 2)
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(size=4))
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(family = "mono", face = "bold"))

ggsave("RPlot_test.jpeg", p)
```